# Disable (unclickable and greyed out) listview items

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with a custom ArrayAdapter. Some items of my list are TextView and some others are CheckedTextView. I want to disable some items when certain CheckedTextViews are checked.

I know how to disable items in the adapter with View.setEnabled(false) but how can I do this outside the adapter in the setOnItemClickListener, once the list is created?

Comment: How will you get OnItemClickListener for CheckedTextViews outside of adapter?

Comment: setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener) is available on ListView objects. EDIT: Ok I understand your question, I will do what I said previously and override onItemClick to get the position of the item clicked.